# Flask User Login email-validator

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, email-validation

I am using flask to create user login and I encounter this error when I try to run my program. As you can see I already have email-validtaor installed, so why is it still telling me to install it?

Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support.

This is my pip list that show email-validator installed.

Peters-Air:~ peterkogolo$ pip list
Package                           Version

---

backports.entry-points-selectable 1.1.0
bcrypt                            3.2.0
blinker                           1.4
certifi                           2021.10.8
cffi                              1.15.0
click                             8.0.3
distlib                           0.3.3
dnspython                         2.2.1
email-validator                   1.2.1
filelock                          3.3.1
Flask                             2.0.2
Flask-Bcrypt                      1.0.1
Flask-Login                       0.5.0
Flask-Mail                        0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy                  2.5.1
greenlet                          1.1.2
idna                              3.3
itsdangerous                      2.0.1
Jinja2                            3.0.2
MarkupSafe                        2.0.1
pip                               21.3.1
pipenv                            2021.5.29
platformdirs                      2.4.0
pycparser                         2.21
setuptools                        57.4.0
six                               1.16.0
SQLAlchemy                        1.4.26
virtualenv                        20.9.0
virtualenv-clone                  0.5.7
Werkzeug                          2.0.2
WTForms                           3.0.0

Comment: can you check that this pip is the pip that comes with the python version you are using. sometimes there can be multiple pip installations from different pythons

Comment: my python version is 3.9.7 and my pip version is 21.3.1. Is there anything wrong with that? should I upgarde or downgrade?

Comment: If you’re not already using a virtual environment, I suggest you do so. That will really clarify whether the `pip list` you’re seeing is the actual set of packages your app is accessing. See [Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/venv.html).